# VBA Pivot Filter by month period

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to create a macro for my dynamic table that filter the elements showing only those which happened on a certain month. I have the following script:

```
Sub Change_Filter()
    Dim months As Variant
    Dim month As Integer
    Dim filter As String
    months = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
    month = CInt(Sheets("Índice").Range("I12"))
    filter = "xlAllDatesInPeriod" & months(month - 1)
    Worksheets("pivotTable").Activate
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters.Add Type:=filter
End Sub
```

However, when I reach the last line I get the error `Error 13: Type mismatch`.

I have even tried to just use

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlAllDatesInPeriodJanuary
```

to see if it works, but I then get `Error 1004: Error defined by the application or object`.
[This](https://ibb.co/K9LjwkY) is how my dynamic table looks and [this](https://ibb.co/1bwD0WT) is the table where the data comes from.

Can it be related to the fact that my dynamic table does not have a date field?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your date field needs to be in the pivot  table model to be used as a field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have it as a row you should be able to use the code how you have it. If you have date added as a filter field you need to do something like the following:

```
Sub PageItemFilter()
Dim pvtF As PivotField
Dim pvtI As PivotItem

Set pvtF = Worksheets("Sample").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date")
For Each pvtI In pvtF.PivotItems
    If DateValue(pvtI.Name) >= Range("C2").Value2 And DateValue(pvtI.Name) <= Range("C3").Value2 Then
        pvtI.Visible = True
    Else
        pvtI.Visible = False
    End If
Next pvtI

End Sub
```

Or maybe use a slicer

```
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches.Add2(ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1"), _
        "Date", , xlTimeline).Slicers.Add ActiveSheet, , _
        "Date", "Date", 239.25, 449.25, 262.5, 108

  
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("NativeTimeline_Date"). _
        TimelineState.SetFilterDateRange "09/01/2021", "09/30/2021"
```

Split month from year in your data table
define a new column and use the following formula to split out the month

```
=TEXT(MONTH(Date),"MMMM")
```

I haven't tested the below but it should do what you are looking for.

```
Sub PageItemFilter()
Dim pvtF As PivotField
Dim pvtI As PivotItem
months = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
month = CInt(Sheets("Índice").Range("I12"))+1

Set pvtF = Worksheets("Sample").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date")
For Each pvtI In pvtF.PivotItems
    If Month(DateValue(pvtI.Name)) == month Then
        pvtI.Visible = True
    Else
        pvtI.Visible = False
    End If
Next pvtI

End Sub
```

Comment: That's it, I don't have the date as a field, I have it only as a filter. But what if I do not want to show the items between a certain date range, but those happened on a specific month no matter the day or year? How should I code it? @Richard D

Comment: @luiscri look at the timeline object and slicer object I will try add some code in my answer that will show you how to add one .

Comment: @Luiscri  EDIT: misread your comment. I would look at making a new column in your table splitting the year and month values and using only the month values for your ranges

Comment: That's it, I had to do some tweaks to your response, but I finally achieved to had it working. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This was my final solution to the problem:

```
Sub Change_Filter()
    Dim pvtF As PivotField
    Dim pvtI As PivotItem
    Dim selected_month As String
    Dim months
    Set months = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    selected_month = Worksheets("Índice").Range("I12")
    
    If selected_month = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Seleccione un mes de la lista")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With months
        .Add Key:="Enero", Item:=1
        .Add Key:="Febrero", Item:=2
        .Add Key:="Marzo", Item:=3
        .Add Key:="Abril", Item:=4
        .Add Key:="Mayo", Item:=5
        .Add Key:="Junio", Item:=6
        .Add Key:="Julio", Item:=7
        .Add Key:="Agosto", Item:=8
        .Add Key:="Septiembre", Item:=9
        .Add Key:="Octubre", Item:=10
        .Add Key:="Noviembre", Item:=11
        .Add Key:="Diciembre", Item:=12
    End With
    
    Worksheets("pivotTable").PivotTables("PivotTable1").RefreshTable
    Set pvtF = Worksheets("pivotTable").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date")
    With pvtF
        .ClearAllFilters
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    End With
    
    For Each pvtI In pvtF.PivotItems
        If Month(pvtI.Name) = months(selected_month) Then
            pvtI.Visible = True
        Else
            pvtI.Visible = False
        End If
    Next pvtI
    Worksheets("pivotTable").Activate
End Sub
```

The `Month()` function and specifying the pivot field `.NumberFormat` property did the trick for me. Also, check that you do not have any blank cell on your pivot table data range, as it caused me some trobles.